# FIM2010 R2 SP1 service account requirements on database after installation

Tags: security, sql-server, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010

We're in the process of updating our Forefront Identity Manager to 2010 R2 SP1. The SQL Server instance for the old installation has the FIM service account in the sysadmin role, as is required for the installation. However, our security team (as well as myself) would like to reduce the permissions to the account as much as possible on the new installation. What are the minimum required permissions for the FIM account on SQL Server after the installation is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking everywhere and not finding any documentation or advice on this, I decided to do some of my own testing. After the FIM installation was completed and FIM was running properly, I reduced the service account's rights to have only dbowner on the FIM database and no server roles. We've had no issues with this setup, so I consider this to be an answer.